# Secure application credentials in iOS and android mobile application?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, security, titanium

What is the best way to  store my application credentials in my mobile app?

Is there a way I can do this without storing the  application credentials in the mobile application itself? (I need these credentials to make service calls to my web service)

Comment: This is likely to vary by OS

Answer (score 0):

In case of IOS I think the best way to save in keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Both iOS and Android provide system-level features to do this. iOS offers the Keychain, which protects the credentials on behalf of the application storing them. Android offers the KeyChain, which does the same thing...but this feature was only added in Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0); for prior versions of Android, there is no good solution to this question.